# How to add 2 columns in where condition?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, arel

How can I do something like

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE column_a + column_b >= 10
```

with ActiveRecord::Relation or Arel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Model.where('column_a + column_b >= 10')` should be what you need for Active Record.

Comment: Sorry. Should have said "without using pure SQL"

Comment: Afaik there no other performant way without using a sql fragment.

Comment: I think he's right. Sometimes there is no way to avoid using sql fragments.